# XPages: Creating JSON String from large amount of document

Tags: java, json, dojo, xpages

I have been trying to create a Json String with a large amount document but using the below code but i get out of range or have to wait till up to 5min  b4 the String is greated any idiea how i could optimise the code?

```
public String getJson() throws NotesException {
    ...
    View view1 = ...;
    ViewNavigator nav =view1.createViewNav();
    ViewEntry ve = nav.getFirst();  
    JSONObject jsonMain = new JSONObject();     
    JSONArray items = new JSONArray();
    Document docRoot = null 
    while (ve != null) {
    docRoot= ve.getDocument();
        items.add(getJsonDocAndChildren(docRoot));
        ViewEntry veTemp = nav.getNextSibling(ve);
        ve.recycle();
        ve = docTemp;
    }
    jsonMain.put("identifier", "name");
    jsonMain.put("label", "name");
    jsonMain.put("items", items);
    return jsonMain.toJSONString();
}

private JSONObject getJsonDocAndChildren(Document doc) throws NotesException {

    String  name = doc.getItemValueString("Name");
    JSONObject jsonDoc = new JSONObject();
    jsonDoc.put("name", name);
    jsonDoc.put("field", doc.getItemValueString("field"));
    DocumentCollection responses = doc.getResponses();
    JSONArray children = new JSONArray();
    getDocEntry(name,children);//this add all doc that has the fieldwith the same value name to children
    if (responses.getCount() > 0) {
        Document docResponse = responses.getFirstDocument();

        while (docResponse != null) {
            children.add(getJsonDocAndChildren(docResponse));
            Document docTemp = responses.getNextDocument(docResponse);
            docResponse.recycle();
            docResponse = docTemp;
        }

    }
    jsonDoc.put("children", children);
    return jsonDoc;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first determine where the time is spent in your code. Maybe it is in `doc.getResponses()` or `responses.getNextDocument()` which you did not show here.

The obvious optimization which could be done within your code snippet is the following:

Basically you have some data structure called Document and build up a corresponding in memory JSON structure consisting of JSONObjects and JSONArrays. This JSON structure is then serialized to a String and returned.

Instead of building the JSON structure you could directly use a JsonWriter (don't know what JSON library you are using but there must be something like a JsonWriter). This avoids the memory allocations for the temporary JSON structure.

In `getJson()` you start:

```
StringWriter stringOut = new StringWriter();
JsonWriter out = new JsonWriter(stringOut);
```

and end

```
return stringOut.toString();
```

Now everywhere where you creating JSONObjects or JSONArrays you invoke corresponding writer methods. e.g.

```
private void getJsonDocAndChildren(Document doc, JsonWriter out) throws NotesException {
     out.name("name");
     out.value(doc.getItemValueString("Name"));
     out.name("field");
     out.value(doc.getItemValueString("field"));
     DocumentCollection responses = doc.getResponses();
     if (responses.getCount() > 0) {
          Document docResponse = responses.getFirstDocument();
          out.startArray();
          ...
```

Hope you get the idea.

Comment: and when would av to end the array

Comment: at the end of the if block

Comment: do u av a workin exaple becus i am having problem with the calling script at the area  items.add(getJsonDocAndChildren(docRoot)); how do i pass that to Writer considering the recursive function

Comment: see my code of `getJsonDocAndChildren`: You pass the writer as second parameter

Comment: But is a recursive function that is abeeb added to children so how do u recall the funtion and what is been return?

Comment: corrected my code snippet: Nothing is returned (void) since all data went into the JsonWriter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88689/discussion-between-simon-peter-and-wero).

Comment: hello is it posible to write my output to a file? becuase with very big data i get out of memory from StringWriter

Comment: yes, just use something like `new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(destination), "UTF-8"))` instead of `new StringWriter()`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things here, ranging from general efficiency to optimizations based on how you want to use the code.

The big one that would likely speed up your processing would be to do view operations only, without cracking open the documents. Since it looks like you want to get responses indiscriminately, you could add the response documents to the original view, with the "Show responses in hierarchy" option turned on. Then, if you have columns for `Name` and `field` in the view (and no "Show responses only") columns, then a `nav.getNext()` walk down the view will get them in turn. By storing the `entry.getIndentLevel()` value for each previous entry and comparing it at the start of the loop, you could "step" up and down the JSON tree: when the indent level increases by one, create a new array and add it to the existing object; when it decreases, step up one. It may be a little conceptually awkward at first, having to track previous states in a flat loop, but it'd be much more efficient.

Another option, also having the benefit of not having to crack open each individual document, would be to have a view of the response documents categorized by `@Text($REF)` and then making your recursive method look more like:

```
public static void walkTree(final View treeView, final String documentId) {
    ViewNavigator nav = treeView.createViewNavFromCategory(documentId);
    nav.setBufferMaxEntries(400);
    for (ViewEntry entry : nav) {
        // Do code here

        walkTree(treeView, entry.getUniversalID(), callback);
    }
}
```

(That example is using the OpenNTF Domino API, but, if you're not using that, you could down-convert the for loop to the legacy style)

As a minor improvement any time you traverse through ViewNavigators, you can set `view.setAutoUpdate(false)` and then `nav.setBufferMaxEntries(400)` to improve the internal caching.

And finally, depending on your needs - say, if you're outputting the JSON directly to an HTTP response's output stream - you could use `JsonWriter` instead of `JsonObject` to stream the content out instead of building a huge object in memory. I wrote about it with some simple code here: https://frostillic.us/blog/posts/EF0B875453B3CFC285257D570072F78F

Comment: can u pls give a working example, that work with loop